# Double buffering in the console (display)?

Tags: c++, c, console

I'm trying to create a console pong game but have run into the following issue.
I have the following:

```
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        clearScreen();

        std::stringstream sstr;
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        {
            sstr << "Mooooooo \n";
        }
        printf(sstr.str().c_str());
        restThread(50);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output I would expect is for Moo to be written 20 times and for the contents of the screen to never actually change. However it flickers from time to time. I suspect this is because the output is shown to the screen before it is fully drawn. Is there a way around this? eg, not showing the user anything until all the characters have been drawn to the screen?

Thanks

Comment: Again, C++ does very little for console output (`cout` doesn't even need to actually go to console, that's just convention). What platform? You might have better luck looking into a ready-made simple engine like SDL or SFML.

Comment: @GMan I usually make games in OpenGL and or SDL, I'm just trying this for the fun and novelty of it. I'm trying to target Windows and Linux

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's the curses/[ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) library, which requires you to refresh the screen before anything is displayed. It's pretty ubiquitous in terms of platform support.